# mplayer/ffmpeg How to set caca filter's output size

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, filter

I'm curious how different clips would look like in ASCII art. So I'm trying [caca](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#toc-caca).

To just play, I use `mplayer -vo caca $FILE`.

But that creates an output of quite small size.

**How can I change that size?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found. Caca library is driven mostly by environment variables rather than filter params.

```
export CACA_GEOMETRY=200x78
mplayer -vo caca $INPUT
```